# Linux replace column in filename with parent directory name

Tags: linux, shell, replace, find, sh

I have a file structure that looks like this:

Surge/Track_000000/000_extracted.csv

where the zeroes can be replaced by any numberical value

The files 000_extracted.csv look like:

```
Timestep  ElementID  SE
1   100   .5
2   100   1.3
3   100   .7
4   100   .2
```

Ideally what I would like to have is a resulting file that looks like this:

```
Track    Timestep  ElementID  SE
0000000    1   100   .5
0000000    2   100   1.3
0000000    3   100   .7
0000000    4   100   .2
```

Where the 0000000 is the 7 digit track code from the parent directory name.

As I first step I want to append the directory name (Track_000000) to the filename.  So it would go from 212_extracted.csv to Track_000000_212_extracted.csv.

I tried this:

```
for i in 'ls ./Surge/'
do
for j in 'ls ./Surge/$i/'
do
mv -v './Surge/$i/*.csv' './Surge/$i/$i-*.csv'
done
done
```

This is not working.  While $i should be Track_0000000, instead it is telling me it is /Surge/.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
K

Answer (score 2):

Something along these lines:

```
for dir in /Surge/*; do
    prefix=$(basename $dir)
    trk=${prefix#Track_}

    for file in $dir/*.csv; do
        awk '{ print TRK, "   ", $0 }' TRK=$trk < $file > ${prefix}_${file}
    done
done
```

Comment: This is not working for me.  This code wants to add another $dir on it seems....for instance it keeps telling me: bash:Track_1234566_Track_1234567/123_extracted_data.csv: no such file or directory.  This is true.  It should be looking for Track_1234567/123_extracted_data.csv instead.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use back apostrophe: ` instead of ':

```
for i in `ls ./Surge/`; do
    for j in `ls ./Surge/$i/`; do
       mv -v './Surge/$i/*.csv' './Surge/$i/$i-*.csv'
    done
done
```

Comment: you are suggesting a bad practise... dont use ` instead use brackets

Comment: I strongly suggest not to use backtick anymore. It has so many flaws, it shouldn't be promoted. Use `$(cmd)` instead.